# Paginating posts according to tags

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent

When a user clicks on a tag say "mobile", I'm trying to get all the posts that are associated with that tag through this method:

```
public function getRelevantPostsFromTag($tag)
{
    $posts = [];

    $tag = Tag::where('name', '=', $tag)->first();

    foreach ($tag->posts as $post) {
        array_push($posts, $post);
    }

    return collect($posts);
}
```

I'm then trying to paginate the returned collection by trying to do so:

```
$posts = $this->postRepository->getRelevantPostsFromTag($tag);
$posts = $posts->paginate(8);
```

But I'm getting a method paginate does not exist error. Is the application of paginate on a custom collection disallowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this to get all posts by tag name and paginate.

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($name) {
    $q->where('name', $name);
})->paginate(...);
```

`Illuminate\Support\Collection` does not have a paginate method.

If you already have a collection you can manually create a paginator and use something like `Collection@forPage` to help slice it for you to pass into the paginator.